# Dot adding at the end of word in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

In my UITextView whenever I have been giving multiple spaces a dot is adding at the end of the word. As I am using that for getting email id, I don't want any dots, How to avoid this?. I have added that UITextView in IB. Do I need to do any changes there?

Comment: @Prince, I have added UITextview thro IB. I have not done any modification in code after that.

Comment: In xib just set the correct property of text box to no instead of Default

Comment: The "dot" is called a *period*.

Comment: @Wolvorin I tried with relevant properties, none seems working.

Answer (score 4):

It's a keyboard setting. Go to settings->general->keyboard and disable `"." shortcut`. It inserts period if you add two consecutive spaces.

Comment: Can u pls tell me which settings?

Comment: If we changes in settings then it will affect to whole system right?

Answer (score 2):

In interface builder, set the keyboard option to E-mail address.

Comment: Already keyboard is in E-mail address only. Still problem exist

Comment: Is this the ... because it reached the edge of the text field or is it an autogenerated period at the end of the sentence?

Comment: WolfinLink Its not reached edge, typing simply 123 if i give space two spaces its changing to 123. I have to wait sometimes before giving second space then dot is not adding.